# postfix: remap user credentials for relayhost

Tags: postfix, smtp-auth

I've been trying to figure out how to have postfix remap the username for an SMTP relay host similar to how fetchmail does for the inbound email.

In my fetchmailrc I have something that looks like this:

```
poll "mx.my_isp.com" protocol POP3 :
  user "myuser@my_isp.com" there with password "secret_password" is "user1" here
```

This mapping has to be reversed for the outbound mail now.

The inbound smtp from the mail client is successfully validated, but when postfix attempts to relay the outbound mail, it needs to reverse my fetchmail mappings; so some form of relay_user_map that would allow me to reverse the user mapping from fetchmail; something that would effectively perform this mapping:

```
user "user1" here is "myuser@my_isp.com" with password "secret_password" there
```

With "relayhost=smtp.my_isp.com" in main.cf

I would expect something like "relay_user_map=hash:/etc/smtp_user_map" in the main.cf, but so far I've been unable to find a way to reverse this user mapping.

If someone could just point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Is [this](https://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html#client_sasl_sender) what you are searching for?

Comment: Very possibly; I'll have to look into it further when I get home.

Comment: Thanks.  This was the key.

Sorry this took so long to validate, but it turns out that when my ISP added this requirement, they added several others that I only discovered once I put the mapping into  place.